# Javasctip variable not assigned

Tags: javascript

Why is username undefined? I can be sure that the JSON file format is right.

I need set username as the global variable, is there any way i can workaround this?

```
var loginProfile = 'link to JSON file';
var username;
$.getJSON(loginProfile, function (data) {
    username = data.USERNAME;
});

alert(username);
```

Comment: please google and read about `callback` it will help :)!

Answer (score 0):

Because your getJSON is asynchronous, the value is undefined when you put alert. Instead you can use callback or function as below and display. Try this,

```
var loginProfile = 'link to JSON file';
var username;
$.getJSON(loginProfile, function (data) {
    username = data.USERNAME;
    printUserName(username);
});

function printUserName(name){
  alert(name);
}
```

Comment: I need it assigned to a global variable. The function wont work for my case.

Comment: still you can assign to a global variable

Comment: I tried assigning username = name in fn printUserName(), still don't have a global username variable

Comment: does the alert shows the name?

Comment: within the function yes, but i need it out of the function.

Comment: you need to understand the javascript basics first. I think you are from different background. you can use the variable within the scope and only if the variable value is assigned. Otherwise it will be undefined

Comment: yes i know, thats what i'm asking if there's any other workaround. putting it into another function is not helping.